# Removing strings from beginning and end of .txt files in directory?

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a set of 1-line .txt files in a directory. They all have the same basic format, which I have pasted below labelled 'input':

For every file in the directory, I would like to remove the string at the beginning and the end so that I only have the text that I am interested in, so that each file looks the 'output':

Input:
`<s> Text here that I want to keep </s> (31ca4166c37a_.76)`

Output:
`Text here that I want to keep`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome! The strings beginning an end are always yhe same?

Comment: The <s> and the </s> are always the same, and there is always a string in brackets at the end. The contents inside the brackets is different for each file. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Using good old `ed` to edit the files:

```bsh
for file in dir/*.txt; do
  ed -s "$file" <<'EOF'
s!^<s> *!!
s!</s>.*$!!
w
EOF
done
```

(As a general rule, most of the time you find yourself thinking about the non-standard `sed -i`, you should consider using `ed` instead.)

Answer (score 0):

With sed

```
sed -i.bak 's|^<\/s>\s\(.*\)\s<\/s>.*$|\1|' 1-line.txt
```

Tests

```
echo "</s> Text here that I want to keep </s> (31ca4166c37a_.76)" | sed 's|^<\/s>\s\(.*\)\s<\/s>.*$|\1|'
Text here that I want to keep
```

To apply in all files in a folder there is no way to do it using only sed. You'll need to use at least the `find` utility together:

```
find . -type f -exec sed -i.bak 's|^<\/s>\s\(.*\)\s<\/s>.*$|\1|' {} \;
```

This command will create a `.bak` file for each changed file.

**Notes:**

- The `-i` argument for `sed` command is a GNU extension, so, if you are running this command with the BSD's `sed` you will need to redirect the output to a new file then rename it.
- Although specified in POSIX, some `find` implementations do not have  the `-exec` argument, so, you will need to use a `| xargs` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I propose this:

```
sed 's;^[[:blank:]]*<[^>]*>[[:blank:]]*\(.*\)<.*>.*$;\1;' foo
```

Output:

```
Text here that I want to keep
```

This works if the tags have more than one letter, and any letter, and removing any white space at begginig and end, example:

```
<br> Text here that I want to keep    </br> (31ca4166c37a_.76)
```

Answer (score 0):

With any POSIX awk (assumes that every `<s>` and `</s>` do come in ordered pairs on every line like in the sample input you provided):

```
$ awk -F'[[:blank:]]*</?s>[[:blank:]]*' '{print $2}' file
Text here that I want to keep
```

With GNU awk for `\s` shorthand:

```
$ gawk -F'\\s*</?s>\\s*' '{print $2}' file
Text here that I want to keep
```

With any POSIX sed:

```
$ sed 's|[[:blank:]]*<s>[[:blank:]]*\(.*[^[:blank:]]\)[[:blank:]]*</s>.*|\1|' file
Text here that I want to keep
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with below command

command

```
sed  -e 's/<\/\?s>//g' -e 's/(.*)//g' filename
```

output

```
Text here that I want to keep
```